# Loading Images from Multiple Folders along with their labels into an array

Tags: python

I am working on a multiclass image classification problem and there are 12 folders inside my training folder and I am trying to load all the images from these 12 folders along with their label in the numpy arrays both X and Y.

This is the code that I am using. I am able to get the images as an array, however I want to know how to get the corresponding labels as well. I'd appreciate the help.

[This is the code that I am using.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHKk4.png)

Comment: Please resist sharing code with a screenshot. It makes it harder to read, harder to copy, harder to reproduce your case. That's why you should copy the code inside of your question instead.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.